# Delphi 7 com Indy 9 roda no Windows 8?

Tags: delphi, windows, delphi-7, indy-9

Bom pessoal muitos como eu que usam apenas o idhttp.get com http no `Delphi 7` padrão indy9, que é simples e não necessita de dll ... ele roda no win8? Porque já pesquisei e só vejo pessoas dizendo atualiza para o 10 mas não vejo necessidade então a pergunta é `Delphi 7` indy9 padrão roda win8 ou não?

Comment: Não sei dizer, mas usar usar uma tecnologia que usa rede criada há 13 anos e que não recebe atualizações é algo insano.

Comment: Obrigado amigão pela resposta ... Testei e para alguns que ainda possuem duvidas o Indy 9 padrão do Delphi 7 infelizmente não funciona no windows 8 ... Então vamos atualizar o indy povo rsrs.

Comment: Tenho sistema rodando cheio de idhttp feito com D7/Indy 9 e rodando uma maravilha no Windows 8 e 10.

A menos que você queira algum recurso muito novo que não havia na época troque para Indy 10, mas se for só por causa do idHTTP não há necessidade

Answer (score 0):

O indy9 funciona sim no windows 8, a questão não é o S.O e sim as technologias empregadas  nos uso do(s) protocolo(s) (smtp e cia) e rede(meio) que vem sofrendo constantes atualizações. Como por exemplo o tipo de autenticação ( Simple Authentication and Security Layer (SASL) )  que no indy10 possui uma implementação bem satisfatória, também tem as versões de TLS e SSL suportadas pelo TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenssl. Resumindo o Indy9 com certeza ainda funciona, entretanto, com certeza é melhor atualizar para o 10 ou superior. Para não ter problema de compatibilidades com alguns servidores smtp ao tentar enviar seus emails.